# Code coverage for laravel dusk

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

Is there any way to get code coverage when running Laravel Dusk?

I know it runs browser tests so it's not scrutinizing code, but is there a way to add a listener to check what code is covered? I did not see anything on this subject now.

Comment: Wondering the exact same thing

Comment: The browser cannot see the code that is being executed.

Comment: i would love to know what routes have been tested? Rather than traditional "code coverage"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conceptually, you need to bootstrap all your requests w/ PHP Unit's code coverage tools.

You can do this with phpunit libraries directly, or via [xdebug's coverage tools](https://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage) (which use phpunit).

From [this sample](https://gist.github.com/jleonardolemos/3599ae185ab1bc6f3901d5881f977fd6) gist that I found, you can start coverage tools based on a couple of _GET parameters passed via the Dusk test.

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
      $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
          $browser->visit(route('test', [
              'test_name' => 'testBasicExample',
              'coverage_dir' => '/app/Http'
          ]))->assertSee('test');
      });
  }
```

The code that does the work is two parts
1. Start collecting based on parameters:

```
$test_name = $_GET['test_name'];
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$current_dir = __DIR__;
$coverage = new SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage;
$filter = $coverage->filter();
$filter->addDirectoryToWhitelist(
    $current_dir . '/..' . ((isset($_GET['coverage_dir']) && $_GET['coverage_dir'])
        ? $_GET['coverage_dir']
        : '/app')
);
$coverage->start($test_name);
```

And 2 end collecting and output:

```
function end_coverage()
{
    global $test_name;
    global $coverage;
    global $filter;
    global $current_dir;
    $coverageName = $current_dir . '/coverages/coverage-' . $test_name . '-' . microtime(true);
    try {
        $coverage->stop();
        $writer = new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\Html\Facade;
        $writer->process($coverage, $current_dir . '/../public/report/' . $test_name);
        $writer = new SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\PHP();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        file_put_contents($coverageName . '.ex', $ex);
    }
}
```

The end collection is called using a clever little trick where the class `coverage_dumper` has just a destructor, which gets called automatically when php ends the process.

The code itself can use a bit of tidy up as far as output paths, and variables go, but from a concept, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Dusk is using Browsers to run tests and the Browser can't see the PHP code that's being executed.
The only way that I see to achieve code coverage with Dusk is to create a option in php artisan serve that would be possible to count and create the coverage file.